# Unable to access UI components in Red Hat Linux Server

Tags: python, user-interface, gramex

I am not able to access the UI components in gramex. I tried all the things I knew. I am using the Red Hat Linux server.
I am getting the following warnings in the logs:

Disallow "/home/gramex/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gramex/apps/ui/node_modules/bootstrap-select/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css". It matches ".*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because Gramex is installed under `/home/gramex/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gramex`.

Please note the dot (`.`) in `/.local/". [FileHandler ignores paths beginning with dot](https://learn.gramener.com/guide/filehandler/#ignore-files).

Solution #1: Please install Anaconda / Python in a path that does not have a `.` in it.

Solution #2: Add this to `gramex.yaml`:

```yaml
# This is the default Gramex configuration.
# Copy it to your gramex.yaml and comment out the line mentioned below:
handlers:
  FileHandler:
    ignore:
      # Comment out or remove the next line
      # - ".*"                    # Hide dotfiles
      - gramex*.yaml              # Always ignore gramex config files
      - "*.py*"                   # Hide Python scripts
```